# Quarkus How to Serve JSP Files

Tags: jsp, quarkus

I've been researching Quarkus and how I could use it for new development while still maintaining my existing JSP base.

Rewriting all of our JSPs to servlets and html files would be unreasonable at this point. That is something we could eventually shoot for, but for now, no. So, I've been trying to configure Quarkus in such a way as to be able to serve my JSP files.

Now here is the caveat, our JSPs are very old and written by folks who basically did not understand JSP technology. They are mostly scriplet code with little to no html surrounding the scriplet.

So I'm starting with the standard Quarkus "getting-started" [application](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-guide) using the bootstrap method. That worked just fine. So I then added a new file to 
`resources->META-INF->resources` named test.jsp. This is a very base file with nothing special added.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Test JSP</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I start up the application using `mvnw compile quarkus:dev` from the application root folder. Everything runs and I can access the default index.html at localhost:8080. However, when I try to load the JSP file, localhost:8080/test.jsp, the browser wants to download the file.

Researching futher, I found and added some settings to the application.properties file (https://quarkus.io/guides/http-reference)

```
quarkus.http.root-path=/
quarkus.servlet.context-path=/resources
```

But then I could only get to the html page through localhost:8080/test/ and still the browser wanted to download the JSP file.

The last thing I have tried was to configure an undertow server, using [forecube/undertow-jsp-sample](https://github.com/fourcube/undertow-jsp-sample) as an example. Unfortunately, using Quarkus' way of starting a development server, the main class does not load, so the undertow container is not started.

I go through all of that to ask, is it possible to serve JSP files using Quarkus? If so, then what am I missing?

Comment: JSPs are not currently supported in Quarkus, see: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5082

Comment: There is support for Qute, a similar templating engine: https://quarkus.io/guides/qute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quarkus doesn't support JSP and I wouldn't expect that they will add support for it. Anyway you can use Struts 2 with Freemarker
https://github.com/apache/struts-examples/tree/master/quarkus

Answer (score 1):

You can use

**Qute Template Engine**

```
 <dependency>
           <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
           <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-qute</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

Quarkus + Qute + RDBMS:
https://github.com/knowledgefactory4u/Quarkus/tree/main/quarkus-qute-crud

Quarkus + Qute + MongoDB: https://github.com/knowledgefactory4u/Quarkus/tree/main/quarkus-qute-mongodb-crud

OR

**Freemarker Template Engine**

```
 <dependency>
         <groupId>io.quarkiverse.freemarker</groupId>
         <artifactId>quarkus-freemarker</artifactId>
         <version>0.2.7</version>
      </dependency>
```

Quarkus + Freemarker CRUD :https://github.com/knowledgefactory4u/Quarkus/tree/main/quarkus-freemarker-crud

Comment: Thanks for the input. I've been wanting to try Qute. But at this time, I don't want to have to rewrite the JSP files. I just wanted to be able to display them within the Quarkus environment.